# What happens If a LGPL-licensed shared libraries are dynamically linked to GPL-licensed files of same package?

Tags: license-compatibility, license-recommendation, lgpl, open-source-definition, floss

I'm integrating a component in my commercial software called ABC, in which some part of code is licensed under LGPL and some part it is licensed under GPL. And there are some shared libraries created from ABC component itself, which are further using/linking dynamically with GPL files of the same component(ABC). So are these shared libraries become subject to GPL?

Comment: Your question as written is trivially "yes" because the LPGL is a set of additional permissions to the GPL (in v3 anyway). Do you have a more specific concern?

Comment: Can you name the specific package that is giving you a question? There is one well-known example that does what you're talking in the source code: FFmpeg, and the team helpfully supply a compile-time option to disable GPL code from the binary in case it's desired. However, without knowing the specific package you're talking about, it's hard to give a good specific answer.